# Get model count in Mongoose pre hooks

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can document count for particular model be acquired in both `save` and `update` Mongoose pre hooks/middlewares?

Considering that `this` is query in `update` hook, this works well:

```
schema.pre('update', function (next) {
  this.model.count().then...
});
```

But in `save` hook this

```
schema.pre('save', function (next) {
  this.count().then...
});
```

results in

> this.count is not a function

[image]

When debugging callbacks, `this` in `save` hook and `this.model` in `update` hook appear to be 'models' (instances of `Model`). What's the difference between them?

Why does model instance in `save` hook miss `count` method? How can these two callbacks be unified to get document count?

I would prefer to stick to `this` and not hard-code a model, because this allows to use ES6 classes conveniently for schema inheritance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually `this.model` will not work for (**pre save hook/middlewares**) `pre.('save'` but `this.model` will work for pre hook of `update`, `findOneAndUpdate` .. etc

for `pre.('save'` hook you need to use `this.constructor` instead of `this.model` like : `this.constructor.count` or `this.constructor.findOne` etc.

In my example assume create **Schema** for **Country**

so you can use like bellow :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

var CountrySchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  //....
});

CountrySchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var self = this;
  self.constructor.count(function(err, data) {
    if(err){
       return next(err);
    }
    // if no error do something as you need and return callback next() without error
    console.log('pre save count==', data);
    return next();
  });
});

CountrySchema.pre('update', function (next) {
  var self = this;
  self.model.count(function(err, data) {
    if(err){
       return next(err);
    }
    // if no error do something as you need and return callback next() without error
    console.log('pre update count===', data);
    return next();
  });
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Country', CountrySchema);
```

**OR**

Can use `mongoose.models['modelName']` like: `mongoose.models['Country'].count()` for example

```
CountrySchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  mongoose.models['Country'].count(function(err, data) {
    if(err){
       return next(err);
    }
    console.log('pre save count==', data);
    return next();
  });
});

CountrySchema.pre('update', function (next) {
  mongoose.models['Country'].count(function(err, data) {
    if(err){
       return next(err);
    }
    console.log('pre update count===', data);
    return next();
  });
});
```

**N.B: Why `this.model` not working in pre hook of `save` ?**

**[Middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)** (also called pre and post hooks) are functions which are passed control during execution of asynchronous functions.

In Mongoose has 2 types of middleware:

> 1. Document middleware and
> 2. Query middleware

1. **Document middleware** is supported for functions.

   `init`, `validate`, `save`, `remove`
2. **Query middleware** is supported for functions.

   `count`, `find`, `findOne`, `findOneAndRemove`, `findOneAndUpdate`, `insertMany`,`update`

In Mongoose **Query middleware** `this.model` is the instance of your model that generated/defined by Mongoose. in this middleware `this` return all *instance variable* that defined by mongoose.

where as in **Document middleware** `this` return all **fields** that you defined not by mongoose so `this.model` not your defined property. for above example I have `name` property so you can get that by `this.name` that will show your **requested value**. But when use `this.contructor` then you will return *instance variable* that are defined by mongoose like return `Model` *instance variable.*

Comment: I would prefer to stick to `this` whenever possible. Thanks for pointing at `this.constructor`. Actually, `count` is supposed to be static method, so this makes sense. I guess that possible explanation is that it is `this.model` that stands out, it looks like it is `Model` constructor, not an instance (and wrong case in property name doesn't help).

Comment: Added some explanation as far I know you can see that @estus

Comment: Actually `count` is deprecated ([docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.count)). You can use `countDocuments()` with same syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the name of the model variable instead of `this`.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var schema = new mongoose.Schema;
schema.add({ name: 'string' });

var Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', schema);

schema.pre('save', function (next) {
  Cat.count(function (err, count) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      console.log('there are %d kittens', count);
    }
    next();
  });
})

var kitty = new Cat({ name: 'Zildjian' });
kitty.save(function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('meow');
  }
});
```

Subsequent executions report the correct count and then perform the save operation.

```
$ node index.js 
there are 0 kittens
meow
$ node index.js 
there are 1 kittens
meow
$ node index.js 
there are 2 kittens
meow
$ node index.js 
there are 3 kittens
meow
```

And documents are being persisted in the database.

```
db.cats.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5873b77454fc2a49fd7ec6cf"), "name" : "Zildjian", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5873b777c051094a0ad5dda2"), "name" : "Zildjian", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5873b7789aad6e4a15018ee8"), "name" : "Zildjian", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5873b77b7628684a24c90b07"), "name" : "Zildjian", "__v" : 0 }
```